# Cakephp routing to same controller

Tags: routes, cakephp-1.3

I want to make it like:

`www.xxx.com/product1`
use order controller's index() and pass product1 as a parameter.

`www.xxx.com/product2`
use order controller's index() and pass product2 as a parameter.

then,

`www.xxx.com/product1/shipping`
use order controller's shipping().

`www.xxx.com/product2/shipping`
use order controller's shipping().

I tried:

```
Router::connect('/:product', 
array('controller' => 'order'),
array(
        'product' => 'product1|product2',
        'pass' => array('product')
)
);
```

and it works for `www.xxx.com/product2`

I tried `/:product/:action` to make it work after `index()` but didn't go well. it shows `missing controller for product1` or something.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd suggest to use some kind of denominator for the fact that you are looking at products at all, say something like `hostname.tld/products/product1` oder shorter `host.tld/p/product1`. That'll make it much easier for you to extend this in the future. You might want to take a look at the concept of REST, or Restful URLs.

If, however, you want to stick with that plan, you should try rewriting you URL with Apache, it will be much faster for the user, easier to keep track for yourself und more flexible as you can write all sorts of patterns, including regex.